# Surprised we didn't have a BSO tag

Tags: discussion

I'm very surprised we didn't have a BSO tag, so I created it. Someone with mod powers might want to create a tag synonym for "bicycle shaped object" and link to BSO.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that it's a useful tag.

Does anybody asking about a BSO on our site know what a BSO is before asking the question?

Does anybody on the internet looking to a solution (that we have) to their problem with a BSO know what a BSO is and that they're dealing with a BSO?

Comment: I see it helpful as a post-facto tag. We can tag BSO-ish questions and when newbies have questions about their BSOs, we can refer them to the tag constellation.

Comment: @RoboKaren That sounds a lot like a meta tag...  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: By those criteria, BSO doesn't really fall under meta-tag: "1. If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. .... 2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it's probably a meta-tag. In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag ...

Comment: i.e., BSO is a type of bicycle same as "tandem" or "unicycle" or "mountain bike"

Comment: BSO is a derogatory term for a low quality bike. I agree with @freiheit that BSO as a tag is not useful for a knowledge seeker, and just as important to me, its use is likely to discourage people from answering questions that are tagged with it, since they are of known problem quality.

Comment: @RoboKaren BSO is not a "type of bicycle" as in MTB or Road bike or tandem. Those terms identify the type of riding that a bike is physically suited for, and are useful to segregate questions for those users that have knowledge only in one specific type of cycling. "BSO" on the other hand is a generic term for a low quality bike whose use is subjective. As a "certified bicycle snob" , there are many bikes that others find acceptable to ride, that I would consider too low quality to ride. The thing that makes this a meta tag is its subjectivity.